# delivery frequency in AnyLogic using GIS

Tags: optimization, routes, gis, anylogic

Can someone explain how to implement different delivery frequency in AnyLogic using GIS Route optimisation?  We are currently having problems getting the vehicles to run at the specified frequency.

For example:

Customer A: 4 times a day
Customer B: 8 times a day

Thank you and best regards

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. Unfortunately, SOF does not work for open-ended "can you explain how" questions. Check this article and ask this on the LinkedIn forum instead: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community

Comment: and for future SOF questions, here are some tips: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow